# Getting a live XML feed into a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Hello :) there is a live XML feed (http://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML3) that shows the bidding price and other data of a resource or currency, e.g. Gold, USD/AUD etc.

I am trying to get this to store on my MySQL database table, but I have no idea on how to import an XML feed into a Database using PHP, so is there a function or a process that I should know of that does this?

All responses are appreciated :) Thanks,
Joshua

Comment: no. there's no function for this in php. Dont' expect there to be one either. PHP is a toolkit full of useful minor tools. Take those minor tools and chain them together to accomplish complex things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested solution:

1. Write a parser that can read the XML format given and extract the different fields per rate (symbol, bid, ...).
2. Then import the data into a MySQL table, one column per field.
3. Have this code run regularly (e.g. each minute) to get the data into the database.

Some articles that possibly help you:

- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp (parse XML)
- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp (write into a MySQL
  DB)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron (run task regularly)

Answer (score 0):

This first javascript will reload this page every certain number of miliseconds (60000 for one minute for example). Just replace the pieces between angle brackets with the proper information.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = "<url_of_php_script>";
        }
        , <time_between_updates);
    };
</script>
```

And use something like this php:

```
<?php
    // Code here to parse XML, putting it into MYSQL
?>
```

You should be able to parse the XML using something like this webpage as a start (or a simple google search): http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

(or use @fjc's links)

Comment: Hi there, So basically, I need a js file and a PHP file on my server, the js file will load the xml live feed to the server, then the PHP will get this XML, parse it and then will put it into the MySQL?

Comment: Kind of, or run it on a cron job like @fjc said. (as in hit the web page in some language multiple times, that will parse the information every minute or so and put it into mysql). There are a ton of ways to do what you're asking.